# Could not find solver for: http-01 when set up docker registry with lets encrypt?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, docker-registry

I've tried to setup private registry using official docs.

my docker-compose.yml file is

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  my-registry:
    image: registry:latest
    container_name: my-registry
    env_file:
      - registry_config
    volumes:
      - registry:/var/lib/registry
      - ./data/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    ports:
      - "443:5000"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  registry:
```

registry_config file is

```
REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000
REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST=https://my-domain.com:443
REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=my-secret
REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_CACHEFILE=/etc/letsencrypt/cache.json
REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=my-email@email.com
REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_HOSTS=["my-domain.com"]
```

I got error

```
my-registry    | 2019/10/31 14:36:54 [INFO][my-domain.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
my-registry    | 2019/10/31 14:36:55 [INFO][my-domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: dns-01
my-registry    | 2019/10/31 14:36:55 [INFO][my-domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: http-01
my-registry    | 2019/10/31 14:36:55 [INFO][my-domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: tls-alpn-01
```

in case of request like `https://my-domain.comm/v2/_catalog` I have error:

my-registry    | 2019/10/31 14:36:55 http: TLS handshake error from 184.22.214.103:58383: map[my-domain.com:[my-domain.com] acme: Could not determine solvers]

`cache.json` file is

```
{
    "Email": "my-email@email.com",
    "Reg": {
        "body": {
            "resource": "reg",
            "id": 11111111,
            "key": {
                "kty": "EC",
                "crv": "P-384",
                "x": "abababab",
                "y": "abababab"
            },
            "contact": [
                "mailto:my-email@email.com"
            ],
            "agreement": "https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf"
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/reg/11111111",
        "new_authzr_uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-authz",
        "terms_of_service": "https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf"
    },
    "Key": "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\ndfsfdsfqf3242423fwead3d2d\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "Hosts": [
        "my-domain.com"
    ],
    "Certs": null
}
```

It's very strange for me that `Certs` key is null

How to config docker registry with lets-encript correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [docker/distribution/issue 2740](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2740), which refers to [issue 2545](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2545) ("letencrypt disabled tls-sni-01 challenge. registry image doesn't support fallback challenges")

See [LetsEncrypt challenge types](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/).

> This challenge was defined in draft versions of ACME. It did a TLS handshake on port 443 and sent a specific SNI header, looking for certificate that contained the token. It will be [disabled in March 2019](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/march-13-2019-end-of-life-for-all-tls-sni-01-validation-support/74209) because it was not secure enough.

[Issue 2545 includes the workaround](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2545#issuecomment-437085822):

> I finally settled on [`cesanta/docker_auth`](https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth) which was not too bad to configure. This allows me to set roles and access permissions on a per user/device basis.
>
> Using these methods, I now have a private docker registry that is automatically secured with Let's Encrypt. Best of all, it is backed by Amazon S3 as well so I can destroy and re-create the container and not have to worry about losing any images.